# Error message after online registration of event

Tags: civievent, registration, error

We have been using the same online registration system with CiviEvent and same payment processor for some time. 
Suddenly, registrants are getting an error message after submitting a payment through our online registration. The person is registered in CiviCrm and the payment goes through, but they still get the following error message:

*Sorry but we are unable to provide this at the moment.
Could not find valid value for id.
Return to homepage.*

So what happens is that after they pay, they don't know if it went through and then they try to register again so we are getting people who double register.

Comment: Here is info from debugging after I did a test registration:

Comment: backTrace

#0 /home/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(359): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 /home/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Request.php(95): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Could not find valid value for id")
#2 /home/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/StateMachine/Registration.php(52): CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve("id", "Positive", Object(CRM_Event_Controller_Registration), TRUE)

Comment: #3 /home/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Controller/Registration.php(47): CRM_Event_StateMachine_Registration->__construct(Object(CRM_Event_Controller_Registration), TRUE)
#4 /home/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(307): CRM_Event_Controller_Registration->__construct("Event Registration", TRUE, "null", NULL, "false")
#5 /home/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))

Comment: #6 /home/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#7 /home/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1189): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#8 /home/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.basepage.php(134): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke()
#9 [internal function](): CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Basepage->basepage_handler(Object(WP))

Comment: #10 /home/www/www/wp-includes/plugin.php(579): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:1))
#11 /home/www/www/wp-includes/class-wp.php(633): do_action_ref_array("wp", (Array:1))
#12 /home/www/www/wp-includes/functions.php(886): WP->main("")
#13 /home/www/www/wp-blog-header.php(14): wp()
#14 /home/www/www/index.php(17): require("/home/www/www/wp-blog-header.php")
#15 {main}

Comment: What payment processor? Are you using custom profile/fields on the registration form?

Comment: I am using authorize.net and no, I am not using any custom profiles for these events.